# is there a way to bind keyboard shortcut to navigate to specific program window for example a chrome window ?(Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: shortcut-keys

The idea of workspaces and shortcuts for navigation between them is good. Also, I like the linear form of it compared to using a grid.

For now, my specific question is: is there a way to assign a shortcut key for direct navigation to an open program like Chrome or VSCode which isn't in the current workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Xorg only**

1. A simple one-liner to for example switch to an open terminal if one is open, or otherwise launch a terminal is:

   ```
   sh -c "wmctrl -x -a Google-chrome || google-chrome"
   ```

   This uses `wmctrl` to check whether a window with class (`-x`) "Google-chrome" is running, and switches to it (`-a`). If that fails, the command after `||` ("or") is run instead, which launches Chrome. You can leave out the second part (`|| ...`) to obtain what you actually ask: have a hotkey that switches to an application (but then will do nothing if the application is not running).
2. A bash script to do this on steroids is [`jumpapp`](https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp).

**Wayland and Xorg**

`wmctrl` will not work on Wayland, the default display server on Ubuntu 22.04. Options and control are more limited, but ways to implement a run-or-raise behaviour include

1. Assign a keystroke to launch the *n*´th application on the dock or use the existing ones (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>*n*</kbd>.

   Pinned applications keep their position on the dock. Suppose you pinned Chromium on the first position, then by default, <kbd>Supe</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will switch to or launch Chromium.

   You can use `dconf-editor` to edit this shortcut key, i.e., change or add a key binding to that function, or use a command to do so, e.g.

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-1 "['<Super>1', '<Super>w']"
   ```

   This will add the shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to switch to or launch Chrome.
2. A much more powerful and flexible way to implement such feature is to use the extension [Run or raise](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1336/run-or-raise/) by e2rd. It can only be hoped that this extension continues to be supported for future versions of Gnome Shell.